# Elasticsearch script: failed to add a new array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to add a new array field into a document with painless script but failed.

Here is the document to be updated

```
"_source": {
  "a": {}
}
```

I want to add a new array b under a. So I have this script

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.a.b=[params.id]",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "id": "id001"
    }
  }
}
```

But I got below error

```
{
    "status": 400, 
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "object mapping for [a.b] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value", 
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception"
            }
        ], 
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception", 
        "reason": "object mapping for [a.b] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"
    }
}
```

I tried to create an empty array by

```
"ctx._source.a.b=new ArrayList()"
```

And then append element to the array

```
"ctx._source.a.b.add(params.id)"
```

Still got the same error

Could anyone help me point out what the issue is?
Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index?

Comment: @Val you are right, the issue is about the index mapping. I used to created field b and then removed it. Thought a.b is not existed in the final document, it is still defined in the mappings.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. a.b is defined in index mappings because I defined it before. Thought the field is deleted from the document then.